# How can I make the $si as the machine's IP when using docker?

Tags: kamailio

When I try to call from a phone that is registered to an other SIP proxy (not kamailio) and is routed to kamailio, the proxy server wont forward ringing 180 back to the caller, 2 seconds later the caller sends 408 timeout, I was inspecting the packets with wireshark and noticed that $si source IP is 172.18.0.1 which is the container's local IP address, I was thing it's because of that, how can I fix it? I tried using listen = 0.0.0.0:5060 advertise external_IP:5060.

I tried doing a p2p call from a phone that is registered to a cisco sip, and route it towards kamailio.

Comment: Please show exact packet. Not clear which exactly IP is your container IP. $si is usually client's IP(IP from which kamailio got packet).